# How to make Robolectric select a particular spinner item

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

I am new to Robolectric and am at a roadblock. I have some custom event that fires on selection of a item in spinner and i want to test that using robolectric. I saw that ShadowSpinner class provides helper function like stateSpinner.clickFirstItemContainingText to click a particular item. I populate my spinner with proper values which i test printing out each item as

```
 for (int i = 0; i < spinner_items.length; ++i) {
            spinner_items[i] = (String) spinner.getAdapter().getItem(i);
        }
 System.out.println("Spinner Items "
                + Arrays.asList(spinner_items).toString());
```

However when i use clickFirstItemContainingText  with one of the po
pulated values, i get a IllegalArgumentException. No item found containing test which is strange as above code shows that particular value do exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get Robolectric to work with spinners. The problem is that the views for the list-items in the spinner won't exist apart from the one selected. This can be seen as `spinner.getChildCount()` will always return 1. Just call `spinner.setSelection()`.

Comment: To provide fundament to your answer, [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAbsSpinnerTest.java) is a test for the Spinner's Shadow object, notice how `setSelection()` is used.